# Ionic : JAVA_HOME variable different from what I setted

Tags: java, android, variables, ionic-framework, environment-variables

I have an ionic project that works on browser buf if I try to build it and run it on the device , I receive :

```
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/domenico/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
Subproject Path: CordovaLib

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '13.0.1'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
/Users/domenico/Desktop/Magistrale Fisciano/Tesi/tea_frontend/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '13.0.1'.
```

The strange thing is that I already setted the JAVA_HOME variable to java 1.8 but it reads java13, I don't why, in fact :

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is remove all environment variable set for JAVA also uninstall/Remove all versions of Java from your system. Then Freshly install java jdk 8 and then set the environment path after that give it a try. Hope this will work :)

Comment: Ok but there JAVA variable is only one. Why it reads something different?